# T/F: $v_1,\dots,v_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ linearly independent, $u\in\mathbb{R}^n,u\neq0$, then the matrices $uv_1^T,\dots,uv_k^T$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{k}$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and if $u$ is any nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then the matrices $uv_{1}^{T}, uv_{2}^{T}, \dots, uv_{k}^{T}$ are linearly independent.

Is this true or false? Please help me.

Comment: But if by vector product you mean dot-product, then each of the $uv_j^T$ is a number, not a vector, so I assume you'd mean the cross-product, but the cross-product is only defined for $\mathbb R^3$ .Are you referring to something else?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are row vectors $uv_j^T$ is a real number, but if $u$ and $v$ are column vectors, it is a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $a_1uv_1^T + \dots a_kuv_k^T = u(a_1v_1^T+\dots a_kv_k^T)$. Also, if $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $uv^T \neq 0$.

Comment: What does this part $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ mean?

Comment: It means that $u$ and $v$ are non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: and $u(a_1v_1^T+\dots a_kv_k^T)$ is linear combination

Comment: The expression $a_1v_1^T+\dots + a_kv_k^T$ is a linear combination of the vectors $v_1^T, \dots, v_k^T$, while $u(a_1v_1^T+\dots + a_kv_k^T)$ is the product of the $n\times 1$ matrix $u$ with the $1\times n$ matrix $a_1v_1^T+\dots + a_kv_k^T$.

Comment: Vector space is called linearly dependent if $a_1v_1^T+\dots a_kv_k^T=0$ where nonzero vectors $v$ and not all zero scalar $a$ exist. Here, $a_1uv_1^T + \dots a_kuv_k^T = 0$ $u(a_1v_1^T+\dots a_kv_k^T) = 0$. Therefore, the statement is false.

Comment: Am I missing anything?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about the linear (in)dependence of a vector space. Linear (in)dependence applies to a finite set of vectors: a collection of vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ is said to be *linearly independent* if the only solution to the vector equation $a_1v_1 + \dots + a_kv_k = 0$ is the trivial solution (i.e. $a_1 = \dots = a_k = 0$). Why is the statement false?

Comment: well, is there any way to figure out a solution for here?

Comment: Yes. Suppose $\{uv_1^T, \dots, uv_k^T\}$ were linearly independent. What would that imply about $\{v_1^T, \dots, v_k^T\}$?

Comment: they are linearly independent. $uv_{1}^{T}+uv_{2}^{T}+ \cdots +uv_{k}^{T} \neq 0$ right?

Comment: that was stupid sorry. kernel of {$v_{1}^{T}, \cdots , v_{k}^{T}$} is {0}

Comment: $uv_1^T+uv_2^T+\dots uv_k^T\neq 0$ is true, but that does not imply that $\{v_1^T, \dots, v_k^T\}$ is linearly independent.

$\{v_1^T, \dots, v_k^T\}$ is a collection of vectors, it does not have a kernel, a linear transformation has a kernel.

Comment: sorry I'm completely confused right now. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: If we want to determine whether $\{uv_1^T, \dots, uv_k^T\}$ is linearly independent or not, we need to consider the solutions to the vector equation $a_1uv_1^T + \dots + a_kuv_k^T = 0$. Are there any other solutions apart from $a_1 = \dots = a_k = 0$?

Comment: so here, we want to find $a_{i}$ for $u(a_{1}v_{1}^{T}+ \cdots + a_{k}v_{k}^{T} = 0$ and we divide both side by $u$ and we have $a_{1}v_{1}^{T}+ \cdots + a_{k}v_{k}^{T} = 0$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10899/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-mark)

Comment: I've just finished typing, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If we want to determine whether {$uv_{1}^{T}, \dots, uv_{k}^{T}$} is linearly independent or not, we need to consider the solutions to the vector equation $a_{1}uv_{1}^{T} + \cdots + a_{k}uv_{k}^{T} = 0$. $\rightarrow$ $u(a_{1}v_{1}^{T} + \cdots + a_{k}v_{k}^{T}) = 0$. If $uv^{T}=0$, then either $u$ or $v$ is zero. We were given that $u$ is not zero and $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ are linearly independent. Since $u$ is non-zero, this part $(a_{1}v_{1}^{T} + \cdots + a_{k}v_{k}^{T})$ from $u(a_{1}v_{1}^{T} + \cdots + a_{k}v_{k}^{T}) = 0$ has to be zero. Therefore we conclude that solution for $a_{1}uv_{1}^{T} + \dots + a_{k}uv_{k}^{T} = 0$ is $a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{k}=0$, and $uv_{1}^{T}, uv_{2}^{T}, \cdots, uv_{k}^{T}$ are linearly independent if $v$ is linearly independent and $u$ is nonzero vector.

Thanks to Michael Albanese

Comment: Careful. You say $v$ is linearly independent and non-zero but you don't say what $v$ is. If $uv^T = 0$ then either $u = 0$ or $v = 0$. As $u(a_1v_1^T + \dots + a_kv_k^T) = 0$ and $u = 0$, $a_1v_1^T + \dots a_kv_k^T = 0$.